# The image is not displayed in the html layout of letters

Tags: python, html, css, image, email

I am trying to send an email with html code. In it I place my image. But when receiving a letter in the mail, the image is not displayed.

```html
<div class="header__container ">
  <img src="mysite/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="header_img">
</div>
```

However, it does not appear in the email.

```html
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/c33cuVIg8CI8ogTZFezJa6bgoZ97KqPgefyR9YPF6vSGfi1zqQFXkx3AMyB0h8hD338LoBPvMR7JTyIt3F0Y=s0-d-e1-ft#https://sherf201.pythonanywhere.com/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:W2ZhbHNlLDJd">
```

And I get this line in the Img tag.
My email sending code

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()

try:
    server.login(EMAIL_BOT, PASSWORD_BOT)
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    part1 = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_BOT
    msg['To'] = email
    msg["Subject"] = name
    server.sendmail(EMAIL_BOT, email, msg.as_string())
    
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

How do I send an image in my html code?

Comment: Without looking too closely at what you are sending, could you confirm which email client is receiving the email and that it absolutely does have allowance for viewing images? (Mine is always set to not show them as a security measure)

Comment: Gmail and permission to display is given. The letter also doesn't end up in spam. @A Haworth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is not supported in many email clients (Outlook as well). If you try to insert SVG files in Outlook manually you may find that they are converted to JPEG images.

Another aspect is that internet based images (hosted on the server anywhere) are blocked by default in most emails clients. To avoid that you need to add an image as an attachment and then set its `Content-ID` MIME header. After that you can refer to the attached image in the message body (HTML) using the following markup:

```
<img src="cid:MyContenttId">
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a code to the answer that allows you to implement the ability to send an image in a letter.

```
    server.login(EMAIL_BOT, PASSWORD_BOT)
    
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    part1 = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)

    img_data = open('filename', 'rb').read()
    img = MIMEImage(img_data, name = os.path.basename('filename'))
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>'.format('filename'))
    msg.attach(img)

    msg['From'] = EMAIL_BOT
    msg['To'] = email
    msg["Subject"] = name
    server.sendmail(EMAIL_BOT, email, msg.as_string())
```

Then in html:

```
    <div class="header__container ">
        <img src="cid:image" alt="logo" class="header_img">
    </div>
```